# Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed'

Tags: php, exception, serialization, simplexml

I am not sure why this is coming up. I am *not* serializing the XML, but my array that I created from an RSS feed (note this is just a snippet):

```
$game_data = array (
    'sysreqos'  => $game->systemreq->pc->sysreqos,
    'sysreqmhz' => $game->systemreq->pc->sysreqmhz,
    'sysreqmem' => $game->systemreq->pc->sysreqmem,
    'sysreqdx'  => $game->systemreq->pc->sysreqdx,
    'sysreqhd'  => $game->systemreq->pc->sysreqhd,
);
```

Then I serialize it `$some_var = serialize($game_data)` and write to a text file `fputs($fh,$some_var)`.

But it does not get that far, it errors out on the serialize line:

> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed'

Answer (score 31):

You have to cast the XML data to a string because internally they are all `SimpleXMLElement`s.

```
$game_data = array (
                'sysreqos'       => (string)$game->systemreq->pc->sysreqos,
                'sysreqmhz'      => (string)$game->systemreq->pc->sysreqmhz,
                'sysreqmem'      => (string)$game->systemreq->pc->sysreqmem,
                'sysreqdx'       => (string)$game->systemreq->pc->sysreqdx,
                'sysreqhd'       => (string)$game->systemreq->pc->sysreqhd
            );
```

Or perhaps a little bit more elegant:

```
$game_data  = array();
$properties = array('sysreqos', 'sysreqmhz', 'sysreqmem', 'sysreqdx', 'sysreqhd');
foreach ($properties as $p) {
    $game_data[$p] = (string)$game->systemreq->pc->$p;
}
```

Comment: the only reason this confuses me is because when i did it via MYSQL it worked perfect 

insert into tablname value (see above) with no typecasting - 
interesting  but many thanks!!

Comment: When you concat the data into an SQL `INSERT` query string, it will be automatically casted to a string. But if you put the data into some PHP data structure it'll keep it's original datatype (which is a `SimpleXMLElement`).

Comment: super! thanks again. btw. are you able to get votes. I thought your answer was short simple and to the point 

- also i cant find this on google but in php comments i notice some people use the @ sysmbol, why? and how is it used

Comment: The `@` is the error suppression operator that suppresses any error message that might occur. I don't know why this is used in the code you saw without seeing the code.

Comment: i sorry for the delay in response, the @ was used in comments. I see that a lot. //@brow_cow- describes a cow...

Answer (score 9):

In the Classes and Objects docs, there is this: In order to be able to unserialize() an object, the class of that object needs to be defined.

Prior to PHP 5.3, this was not an issue.  But after PHP 5.3 an object made by SimpleXML_Load_String() cannot be serialized.  An attempt to do so will result in a run-time failure, throwing an exception.  If you store such an object in $_SESSION, you will get a post-execution error that says this:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed' in [no active file]:0 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in [no active file] on line 0

The entire contents of the session will be lost.  Hope this saves someone some time!

```
<?php // RAY_temp_ser.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
$_SESSION['hello'] = 'World';
var_dump($_SESSION);

// AN XML STRING FOR TEST DATA
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<families>
  <parent>
    <child index="1" value="Category 1">Child One</child>
  </parent>
</families>';

// MAKE AN OBJECT (GIVES SimpleXMLElement)
$obj = SimpleXML_Load_String($xml);

// STORE THE OBJECT IN THE SESSION
$_SESSION['obj'] = $obj;
```

By: Ray.Paseur

### Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

what i do is as 'Stefan Gehrig' said, cast the XML data to a string

```
$_SESSION['obj'] = (string)$obj;
```