# Object serialization SimpleXMLelement error

Tags: php, symfony

I'm having this problem when I am trying to serialize my class I get the exception

```
Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed.
```

I don't get the error. I am not even using the xml features of PHP.. What does this error mean ?

The code:

```
$test = new \My\Name\Space\MyClass();

die(serialize($test));
```

Comment: There must be some SimpleXML-related stuff involved somewhere -- maybe a sub-property of your class, or of a class you are extending ? Or inside some symfony-related stuff your class would use ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058966/uncaught-exception-exception-with-message-serialization-of-simplexmlelement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `SimpleXmlElement` in the object graph of the `\My\Name\Space\MyClass` instance but it cannot be serialized. Add the [magic `__sleep` method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.sleep) to influence which properties get serialized and which are ignored or [implement the Serializable interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php)

Answer (score 0):

I just made an array of all my attributes in the class and serialized that one, when I get the array back out of the session I unserialize it and load it back in.

I made 2 extra methods in the class. 1 to get the array, and the other to load the array.

I didn't found where the SimpleXmlElement is used in Symfony 2.

And now it works.