# Serialize/unserialize an encapsulated Array of SimpleXML-Elements

Tags: php, laravel

I have from an API-request an encapsulated Array like this:

```
Array
(
[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [link_rewrite] => fashion-supplier
        [name] => Fashion Supplier
        [active] => 1
        [date_add] => 2018-01-18 13:47:30
        [date_upd] => 2018-01-18 13:47:30
        [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [language] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 1
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 2
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [meta_title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
....
```

This data I want to store in the Laravel-Cache. Because of the Simple-XML-Elements inside it is not possible to store the raw data  ("Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed").

Is there a way to convert this complex array-simplexml-object-combination in a storable form? The problem is, I need the XML-Attributes inside, that's why I can't use json_decode(json_encode($array));

Thank you for your help!

Alex

Comment: This existing post might be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912551/serialization-of-simplexmlelement-is-not-allowed-when-saving-in-wordpress-pos