# PHP Session values are not available

Tags: php

I set my $_SESSION variables in one PHP file and in the second I will use this variables, but I don't get the value.

First PHP site:

```
<?php
session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])&& isset($_POST['btnMyVerein'])) {
        $ftp_server = "**********";
        $ftp_username = "****";
        $ftp_pass = "*****";
        $server_file = "******";
        $xmlurl = "ftp://$ftp_username:$ftp_pass%21@$ftp_server/$server_file";
    
        $xml=simplexml_load_file($xmlurl)or die("Can't establish connection");
            foreach($xml->children() as $codes){
                        if($codes->mycode != $_POST['myVerein']){
                            continue;
                        }else{
                            $_SESSION['myFile'] = $codes->myFile;
                        }
            }
        $msg = "Success";
        $msg2 = $_SESSION['myFile'];
        header('Location: mysecondpage.php');
        exit;
    }
    else{
    $msg = "Sorry not good";
    header('Refresh: 2; URL = myindex.php');
}
?>
```

mysecondpage.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $ftp_server = "***********";
    $ftp_username = "****";
    $ftp_pass = "**********";
    $server_file = $_SESSION['myFile'];
    $xmlurl = "ftp://$ftp_username:$ftp_pass%21@$ftp_server/$server_file";
?>
```

In mysecondpage.php file the $server_file is not set, because the $_SESSION['myFile'] is empty.

Any hint why?

Comment: Maybe you never reach `$_SESSION['myFile'] = $codes->myFile;`?

Comment: I checked it and this is working. The $_SESSION['myFile'] is set correclty in the fist PHP file..

Comment: How exactly are you executing these PHP scripts? In the browser or in the terminal?

Comment: In the browser, I only copied the PHP section. I think the HTMl section and so on is not important for the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally with the hint of @ch1puha i found the solution:

the cast to (string) was missing in the allocation of the session variable.

```
<?php
session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])&& isset($_POST['btnMyVerein'])) {
        $ftp_server = "**********";
        $ftp_username = "****";
        $ftp_pass = "*****";
        $server_file = "******";
        $xmlurl = "ftp://$ftp_username:$ftp_pass%21@$ftp_server/$server_file";
    
        $xml=simplexml_load_file($xmlurl)or die("Can't establish connection");
            foreach($xml->children() as $codes){
                        if($codes->mycode != $_POST['myVerein']){
                            continue;
                        }else{
                            $_SESSION['myFile'] = (string)$codes->myFile;
                        }
            }
        $msg = "Success";
        $msg2 = $_SESSION['myFile'];
        header('Location: mysecondpage.php');
        exit;
    }
    else{
    $msg = "Sorry not good";
    header('Refresh: 2; URL = myindex.php');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is session saving?? If no use this: **session_commit()** before header(...)

**P.S.** Sorry, can't write comments yet

Comment: session_commit — Alias of session_write_close()

Comment: If I add this line, I get the error 'PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed' displayed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058966/uncaught-exception-exception-with-message-serialization-of-simplexmlelement maybe it helps you